# Converting this Excel formula to Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, excel-formula

My Javascript knowledge is very limited and I was wondering if someone could give me a hand converting this Excel formula into Javascript.

Please see the formula below

```
=ROUNDDOWN(
    IF(
        I7 = 10000,
        88.4% * (I7/107*7),
        IF(
            I7 = 20000,
            89.4 * (I7/107*7),
            IF(
                I7 = 40000,
                90.40 * (I7/107*7),
            )
        )
    ),
    0
)
```

I7 is the input

Basically, anything between 10000 and 19999 uses 88.4% * (I7/107*7)

20000 and 39999 uses 89.4 * (I7/107*7)

40000 and above use 90.40 * (I7/107*7)

Round down to the nearest whole number and output

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And the problem/question is?

Comment: _"Basically anything between 10000 and 19999..."_ - That's not what the formula does...

Answer (score 0):

This is what you asked, not what the formula did

```js
const calculate = num => {
  if (num < 10000) return "N/A";
  num = num / 107 * 7;
  let pct = 1/100;
       if (num < 20000)  pct *= 88.4;
  else if (num < 30000)  pct *= 89.4;
  else if (num >= 40000) pct *= 90.40;
  return Math.round(num * pct)
}

console.log(
calculate(10),
calculate(10000),
calculate(15000),
calculate(25000),
calculate(50000)
)
```

Comment: he said **between** 10000 and 19999 ect. ... not equal

Comment: The name of the function is still wrong (and imho shouldn't this answer exist at all)

Comment: let him fix it andreas

Comment: @Eldshe But that's not what the formula does

Comment: you could shorten it more ;) also put the first "num" in ()

Comment: @Eldshe perhaps now

Comment: whoa - mplungjan from EE 15-20 years ago! Remember document.layers? :-)

Comment: Absolutely- and document.images

Answer (score 0):

I write here a basic code so you can follow.

```
function calCell(input) {
  var value;
  switch(true)
  {
    case input >= 10000 && input < 20000 :
      value = Math.floor(88.4 / 100 * (input / 107 * 7));
    break;
    case input >= 20000 && input < 40000 :
          value = Math.floor(89.4 / 100 * (input / 107 * 7));
    break;
    case input >= 40000 :
      value = Math.floor(90.4 / 100 * (input / 107 * 7));
    break;
    default:
    //I don't know what to do if your value < 10000, but you can put it here
    break;
  }
  return value;
}

console.log(calCell(12345));
```

Comment: Fantastic thank you! Below 10000 can output as N/A. Is it possible to add the most basic HTML input and output? I appriciate the help!

Comment: With return N/A your can add this line below the //I don't know... 
    value = "N/A". About the HTML, I think you should create another question on SO, it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Most short and simplified!

```
function RoundDown(num){
if (num >= 10000 && num <20000) {num=num*88.4/100*107*7}
if (num >= 20000 && num <40000) {num=num*89.4/100*107*7}
if (num >= 40000) {num=num*90.4/100*107*7}
return Math.floor(num)
}
```

Comment: Where did the 107 * 7 go?

Comment: 107*7 is not 100.7